„wenn auch...so dennoch" und der Satzbau
Ich habe heute eine Übung gemacht, bei der man entscheiden musste, welcher der zwei folgenden Sätze richtig ist:


Wenn sie auch oft lange arbeiten muss, so ist sie dennoch froh, sich für den Job entschieden zu haben.

Wenn sie auch oft lange arbeiten muss, ist sie dennoch so froh, sich für den Job entschieden zu haben.



Ich habe den zweiten gewählt, aber der erste soll richtig sein.
Satz 1 hört sich besser an (für meine Ohren, zumindest).  Aber ich glaubte, dass das Verb am zweiten Platz, nach dem Komma, stehen musste, also habe ich den zweiten gewählt.
Aber ist es so, dass das Wort „so" hier zu den Wörtern gehört, die in Hinsicht auf die Zweiter-Platz-Regel nicht mitzählen, wie bei „aber"?  Falls das so ist, könnte jemand einen Link zu einer Webseite geben, die solche Wörter auflistet, oder zumindest den Begriff für diese Wörter.  (Ich habe versucht, Informationen über dieses Themas zu finden, aber es ist mir nicht gelungen).

Beide Sätze sind korrekt. Und das Wort "so" zählt immer mit und besetzt das Vorfeld (den ersten Platz im Verbzweit-Hauptsatz); nur "aber" ist anders und steht außen vor dem Verbzweitsatz.
Was in deinen Beispielen passiert, ist etwas anderes: Der Nebensatz kann selbst im Vorfeld (des Hauptsatzes) stehen (zweites Beispiel), aber manche Nebensätze können auch links "außen angehängt" werden. Dann ergibt sich eine Versetzungskonstruktion, etwa in der Art wie andere Typen:

Was das kostet, das konnte er mir nicht sagen ("was"-Satz im Außenfeld, wieder aufgenommen durch "das" im Vorfeld)
Wenn er kommt, dann laufen wir davon. ("wenn"-Satz außen, "dann" im Vorfeld)

Das findet sich ebenfalls im Wikipediaartikel zum Feldermodell, siehe auch in der deutschen WP:  "Korrelat (Grammatik)"
PS, eine Sache, die ich zuerst übersehen habe: Das "so" in deinem zweiten Satz kann man zwar setzen, es muss aber anders verstanden werden als im ersten: "so froh" als Gradangabe zu "froh". Das "so" im ersten Beispiel ist ein Korrelat, das den "wenn"-Satz wieder aufnimmt.

Danke.  Eine alberne Frage: dementsprechend ist in meinen Beispielen der „wenn"-Satz der Nebensatz?

Ja, der Wenn-Satz ist ist ein Nebensatz, weil er dem Rest untergeordnet  ist (selbst dann, wenn er nicht im Inneren des Hauptsatzes steht, wie erläutert).

Daß das Verb an zweiter Stelle stehen muß, ist zwar - grundsätzlich - richtig, aber eine vereinfachende Darstellung. Diese reicht zwar meistens aus, aber eben nicht immer.
Tatsächlich verwendet man, um den deutschen (und nicht nur den, auch skandinavische Sprachen werden so strukturell beschrieben) Satzbau zu beschreiben, heute üblicherweise das sogenannte Feldermodell (Link nur auf Deutsch verfügbar), das ursprünglich von Erich Drach stammt und später zur heutigen Form ausgebaut wurde.
Die grundlegende Form dabei ist die sogenannte "Satzklammer", die das Mittelfeld einschließt und aus der finiten Verbform (zweite Stelle) und dem Rest des Prädikats (letzte Stelle) besteht. Zum Beispiel:

Gestern (-> Vorfeld)
hat (-> "linke" Klammer)
meine Schwester ihr erstes Kind (-> Rest des Satzes)
geboren. (-> "rechte" Klammer)

Linke und rechte Klammer bilden die erwähnte Satzklammer. Innerhalb dieser stehen alle Teile des Satzes, die nicht explizit in anderen Feldern stehen müssen. Diese Satzklammer umschließt das "Mittelfeld", das von einem "Vorfeld" und einem "Nachfeld" umschlossen wird.
Um auf Ihre Frage  direkt einzugehen: die linke Satzklammer enthält entweder ein Verb oder eine Konjunktion. Deshalb stehen "aber" (aber auch "und", "so", ...) an der Stelle, wo sie stehen.

In der linken Klammer steht nie ein Verb und eine Konjunktion!

Der Satz war durch Editieren mißglückt, ich habs korrigiert.
